# Please explain clearly this DB Syntax (Category = @Category or isnull(@Category,'')='')

Tags: sql-server

I saw

```
(Category = @Category or isnull(@Category,'')='')
```

this syntax in `stored procedure`.Please explain clearly above DB Syntax and i am learning Sql Server now.

Comment: it means that either the value in column `Category` has to match the value in the variable `Category` or the variable `Category`  may be empty

Answer (score 2):

This is a pattern used to compare that `@Category` either has no value/empty or it matches the value in the row of the table.

- The `ISNULL` assures it returns an empty string if the value of @Category is `NULL`. The clause therefore returns true always if @Category is empty string or null.
- If `@Category` has a non-empty value, then the clause only returns true if it matches the row of the record.

Note: This is often used in simple search stored procedures with optional parameters. Unfortunately, it often means the stored procedure may have performance limitations since it is unlikely to align very well with indexes or query plans.

Answer (score 1):

```
(Category = @Category or isnull(@Category,'')='')
```

can be read as

```
if the variable @Category is not empty then
  add the constraint that category must match @Category
```

where empty can be NULL or ''

Comment: Ah, I get what you were trying to say now. I think the part that wasn't clear before was the "add the constraint that ...", which isn't literally what the statement does, but is indeed a reasonable translation of the intent.

Comment: @IMSoP No you are correct that it does not really works like that, but it can be explained/translated like this if you want to keep the explanation/translation very simple, which is what the OP asked